# How to connect to xencenter console remotely?

Tags: xenserver, xen

I need to administrate xenserver remotely. I have redirected 443 port in my router and now I can administrate XenServer. But I need to create VMs, how can I use XenCenter console to see VM desktop remotely. What port do I need to redirect?

Answer (score 3):

It's a quite involved procedure. The following blogpost explains what you have to do in great detail:

http://blogs.citrix.com/2011/02/18/using-vnc-to-connect-to-a-xenserver-vms-console/

Answer (score 1):

The article pepoluan posted works great... but Another way which is officially supported by Citrix is to run a windows xp vm and run XenCenter on it. Setup Remote Desktop to your vm and you've got full control.

Comment: Yes, but I want to install VM remotely, right from xencenter, but when I install it I cannot see everything in console

Comment: You should follow the article in that case

Comment: You should setup a XenServer install in your home. Then you can install and configure windows xp with the correct ip for remote deployment. Also install xencenter and configure remote desktop.  Shutdown your local one and export it as an xva. Import it into the remote XenServer and it should boot up at the correct IP address. Now you can just Remote Desktop to the ip and you're in!

Answer (score 0):

If it's XenServer and XCP or role your own, you need to open up some more ports.

Port 22 + 443 is what's normally required.  I have a feeling the VNC console is tunneled over one of those ports with XenServer but if not you may need to open 5900 - 59xx depending on how many VM's you have running.